# How to send integer array as a parameter from endpoint without querystring from url in asp.net core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint that has a parameter that type of integer array.I want send some value from body as a json string.When I tried it , I was getting null value from parameter so I tried to send integer array from url but happen problem about of url length so I want to know that is possible to send it from request body or how to fix url length problem for 5.000 item

request body that I tried

```
{
  "Ids": [349]
}
```

endpoint function

```
[HttpGet]
public void GetModels([FromBody]List<int> Ids)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in general including a body in a GET request is often not considered very RESTful.  It is no longer specifically "banned" by RFC, but it is not typical.  That said, you can make this work in ASP.Net Core using the [FromBody] attribute.

The issue has to do with how you are formatting your JSON body. Using the signature for GetModels that you have listed above, the JSON body doesn't match the parameters.  Your JSON represents a top-level object with a property Ids that is an array of int, not just an array of it (or List).

If you want to use `public void GetModels([FromBody]List<int> Ids)` then your JSON body should simply be an array (e.g. `[349,350,351]`) and nothing else (no brackets, no "Ids" property name).

If you want to use the JSON body you list above, then you need another class to use for model binding, a DTO.  That DTO would look something like:

```
public class IdDto
{
   public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

and then your GetModels method would look like:

> ```
>     [HttpGet]
>     public void GetModels([FromBody] IdDto idDto)
>     {
>        var myIds = idDto.Ids;
>     }
> ```

Lastly, be sure that your GET request has a Content-Type set to `application/json` or ASP.Net will return a 415 "Unsupported Media Type".